# BOOST::ASIO. Making sure io_service.run() is invoked only after async_receive(...) is called?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I have a problem where two threads are called like this, one after another.

`new boost::thread( &SERVER::start_receive, this);`

`new boost::thread( &SERVER::run_io_service, this);`

Where the first thread calls this function.

```
void start_receive()
{   
    udp_socket.async_receive(....);
}
```

and the second thread calls,

```
void run_io_service()
{  
    io_service.run();
}
```

and sometimes the `io_service` thread ends up finishing before the `start_receive()` thread and then the server cannot receive packets.

I thought about putting a sleep function between the two threads to wait a while for the `start_receive()` to complete and that works but I wondered if there was another sure fire way to make this happen?

Comment: There's no need to put the async_receive in its own thread. asio is asynchronous

Comment: Ok, didn't know that, still new using this framework, but then would the async function only work before the `io_service` thread? In other words, is one guaranteed before the other?

Comment: an async operation causes an io_service::work to be alive until the completion handler is called. Thus the io_service::run call will not return until the completion handler is called.

Comment: When `io_service::run` returns after the completion handler is called does it stop blocking and exit? To me it seems that `async_receive` can keep accepting packets for the duration of a program and `io_service::run`  is only initialized at start up?

Comment: see my answer for pre/postconditions. You need to read the docs a few times before it will all make sense. Took me ages to understand it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `io_service.run()`, the thread will block, dispatching posted handlers until either:

1. There are no `io_service::work` objects associated with the `io_service`, or
2. `io_service.stop()` is called.

If either of these happens, the `io_service` enters the stopped state and will refuse to dispatch any more handlers in future until its `reset()` method is called.

Every time you initiate an asynchronous operation on an io object associated with the io_service, an io_service::work object is embedded in the asynchronous handler.

For this reason, point (1) above cannot happen until the asynchronous handler has run.

this code therefore will guarantee that the async process completes and that the asserts pass:

```
asio::io_service ios;    // ios is not in stopped state
assert(!ios.stopped());
auto obj = some_io_object(ios);
bool completed = false;
obj.async_something(..., [&](auto const& ec) { completed = true; });
// nothing will happen yet. There is now 1 work object associated with ios
assert(!completed);

auto ran = ios.run();
assert(completed);
assert(ran == 1);    // only 1 async op waiting for completion.
assert(ios.stopped());  // io_service is exhausted and no work remaining

ios.reset();
assert(!ios.stopped());  // io_service is ready to run again
```

Comment: Great explanation, ASIO developers should use this explanation instead of this one. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html

Comment: I've always felt that asio is a masterpiece, but the documentation let's it down badly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the `io_service` running, create a `work` object:

```
boost::asio::io_service svc;
auto work = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(svc);
svc.run(); // this will block as long as the work object is valid.
```

The nice thing about this approach is that the `work` object above will keep the `svc` object "running", but not block any other operations on it.

Comment: What you're saying is that I can call this before or after the `async_recieve` call?

Comment: no need to control the lifetime of the work object with a pointer. if you want the io service to stop, just call stop() on it.

Comment: I already have a `menu` thread that allows the `io_service` to stop and start but this is an interesting tidbit, thanks!